# How to sanitize "inline javascript" in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am specifically developing an app in ruby on rails and i find that 
the ruby gem "sanitize" is very useful for cleaning the input by user but it does not remove inline javascript which makes it rather useless

I have gone through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923695/how-best-to-sanitize-fields-in-ruby-on-rails) but that does not sanitize inline javascript

Is there any better to do this(any gems or so)?

Comment: Where are you printing it to?

Comment: basically , the user can make a post... and i sanitized that input using "sanitize" gem...but then found later that the gem doesnt take care of inline javascript ...i didnt know how to work around inline javascript

Answer (score 1):

Well you can set a whitelist for sanitize  to only allow specific tags and attributes, so i guess you already got what you are looking for:

```
Sanitize.clean(html, :elements => ['a', 'span'],
    :attributes => {'a' => ['href', 'title'], 'span' => ['class']},
    :protocols => {'a' => {'href' => ['http', 'https', 'mailto']}})
```

Snipped from
http://wonko.com/post/sanitize