# rails controller invoking params of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Submitting the following parameters

```
Parameters: {[...] "physicalinventario"=>{[...] "physicalinventarioitems_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>",85"}}}, "commit"
```

The goal is to intercept  the quantity parameter at the `physicalinventarioitem` controller `create` action, and sanitize it for possible comma as decimal value being input

```
if params[:physicalinventario][:physicalinventarioitems_attributes][:quantity].include? ","
  params[:physicalinventarioitem][:quantity] = params[:physicalinventario][:physicalinventarioitems_attributes][:quantity].tr!(',', '.').to_d
end
```

However, the syntax is wrong as no value after the comma is being handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex answer is fine if you have only one quantity.

**but what if you have multiple quantites,**

eg: `{"0"=>{"quantity"=>",85"},"1"=>{"quantity"=>",90"}}`

**So, here is the answer which also achieves that requirement for multiple nested attributes.**

```
hash = {"physicalinventario"=>{"physicalinventarioitems_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>",85"},"1"=>{"quantity"=>",90"}}}}
```

The code that you require,

```
hash["physicalinventario"]["physicalinventarioitems_attributes"].each do |key, value|
    if value["quantity"].include? ","
    value["quantity"] = value["quantity"].tr!(',', '.').to_f
    end
end
```

**Here is the resultant hash,**

```
`{"physicalinventario"=>{"physicalinventarioitems_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>0.85}, "1"=>{"quantity"=>0.9}}}}`
```

Comment: @Jerome, please check this answer for multiple nested attributes.

Comment: two observations.  the first is that the code should be placed in the create action of the nesting record.  Second, as stated, this is leading to a `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`error.  `params[:physicalinventario][:physicalinventarioitems_attributes].each do |key, value|` will process properly.

Comment: I used `to_f` there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed `["0"]` in the chain to get :quantity.

Should be

```
params[:physicalinventario][:physicalinventarioitems_attribu‌tes]["0"][:quantity]
```

Most convenient Rails way to sanitize(normalize) data in a model. 
To don't create duplicates, more here [How best to sanitize fields in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923695/how-best-to-sanitize-fields-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: the sequence identifier in the chain being missed I agree with.  However, the submission is for multiple nested attributes; thus the digit cannot be invoked without being wrong for the subsequent physicalinventarioitems being submitted...